# Multiple Tableviews on one page for ipad application

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

Working on an application right now with what I hope to implement as a dual `tableview` that splits the users information into two separate tableviews based on the data that they withdraw but I am stuck at the moment. I have been trying to figure a way to do this for a little while now but most of the pages I find on anything close to this aren't exactly what I am looking for. I made sure everything is connected correctly to have the `tableview` produce the custom cells and that everything has a class but I am still having no `tableviewcells`' present themselves probably due to this area of code but I am unsure how to progress. Example of where I am is below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let entityDeckDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Deck", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == otherCardList {

        let cell: cardDetails = otherCardList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cardDetails

        var cardCount = 0
        var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
        let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
        cell.cardCount.text = ""

        let deckCardsSet = listed.cardselections
        print("The set of DeckCards for that Card is \(deckCardsSet.count)")
        for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections{
            let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
            if myDeckCard.cardsstored == entityDeckDescription {
                // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
                myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
                cardCount = (myDeckCards?.numberSelected!.integerValue)!
                if cardCount == 0 {
                    cell.cardCount.text = ""
                } else {
                    cell.cardCount.text = "" + cardCount.description
                }
            }
        }

        switch (listed.cardType) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
            cell.cardAttack?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardType?.text = "Spell"

        case 2:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
            cell.cardType?.text = "Weapon"
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue

        default:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardAttack?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardType?.text = "Minion"

        }
        cell.cardName?.text = listed.name as String
        cell.cardCost?.text = listed.cost.stringValue
        switch (listed.rarity) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Legendary"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        case 2:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Epic"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        case 3:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Rare"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        case 4:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Common"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        default:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Starter"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        switch (listed.cardClass) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xbe/255, green: 0x23/255, blue: 0x0f/255, alpha: 1.0)
        case 2:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        case 3:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x75/255, green: 0x47/255, blue: 0x19/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 4:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xFF/255, green: 0x80/255, blue: 0x00/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 5:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 6:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()

        case 7:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x5E/255, green: 0x03/255, blue: 0x8F/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 8:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x01/255, green: 0xA9/255, blue: 0xDB/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 9:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.magentaColor()

        default:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        return cell

    } else if tableView == classCardList {

        let cell: cardDetails = classCardList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("classcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cardDetails

        var cardCount = 0
        var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
        let listed = classfrc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
        cell.cardCount.text = ""

        let deckCardsSet = listed.cardselections
        print("The set of DeckCards for that Card is \(deckCardsSet.count)")
        for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections{
            let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
            if myDeckCard.cardsstored == entityDeckDescription {
                // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
                myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
                cardCount = (myDeckCards?.numberSelected!.integerValue)!
                if cardCount == 0 {
                    cell.cardCount.text = ""
                } else {
                    cell.cardCount.text = "" + cardCount.description
                }
            }
        }

        switch (listed.cardType) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
            cell.cardAttack?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardType?.text = "Spell"

        case 2:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
            cell.cardType?.text = "Weapon"
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue

        default:
            cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
            cell.heathLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardAttack?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
            cell.cardHealth?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cardType?.text = "Minion"

        }
        cell.cardName?.text = listed.name as String
        cell.cardCost?.text = listed.cost.stringValue

        switch (listed.rarity) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Legendary"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        case 2:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Epic"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        case 3:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Rare"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        case 4:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Common"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        default:
            cell.cardRarity?.text = "Starter"
            cell.cardRarity?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        switch (listed.cardClass) {
        case 1:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xbe/255, green: 0x23/255, blue: 0x0f/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 2:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        case 3:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x75/255, green: 0x47/255, blue: 0x19/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 4:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xFF/255, green: 0x80/255, blue: 0x00/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 5:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)

        case 6:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()

        case 7:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x5E/255, green: 0x03/255, blue: 0x8F/255, alpha: 1.0)
        case 8:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x01/255, green: 0xA9/255, blue: 0xDB/255, alpha: 1.0)
        case 9:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
        default:
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I am fairly sure this is the area of the code that is causing the issues but if you guys think it is elsewhere maybe we can figure out where the issue is coming from. I am still new to coding and always learning as best as I can.

Comment: Where are your numberOfSection and numberOfRows:inSection methods?

Comment: Thanks for checking in LucaD but I think the answer below should work based on what I am seeing :) It seemingly makes sense if I have further issues I will try and ask further in this posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var returnCell: UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == tableOutletHere {
        // initialize cell here

        returnCell = cell
    }

    if tableView == tableOutletHere {
        // initialize cell here

        returnCell = cell
    }

    ...
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnValue: Int = 0

    if tableView == tableOutletHere {
        returnValue = array1.count
    }

    if tableView == tableOutletHere {
        returnValue = array2.count
    }

    ...

    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for :) It looks like my issue was I wasn't actually setting the var correctly nor was doing numberOfRows in section for the second tableview! Thanks If i have further questions I will ask here!

Comment: @cruelty sure! Do not forget to upvote the answer ;)